# MvvmCross creating custom binding to LinearLayout

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to create a custom binding to LinearLayout to allow me create a view dynamically and bind this as a child to LinearLayout.  For anyone familiar with WPF, this is similar to the functionality provided by the ContentControl or any WPF control deriving from ContentControl.  Basically you can create your dynamic content and bind to the Content property of a ContentControl.

Here's what I have for the custom binding:

```
  public class MvxLinearLayoutContentTargetBinding : MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding<LinearLayout>
    {
        public MvxLinearLayoutContentTargetBinding(object target, PropertyInfo targetPropertyInfo) : base(target, targetPropertyInfo)
        {
        }

        protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
        {
            base.SetValueImpl(target, value);
            var view = target as LinearLayout;

            if (view == null) return;

            view.AddView((View)value);
        }

        public override Type TargetType
        {
            get { return typeof(LinearLayout); }
        }
    }
```

Here's how I am attempting to use this new binding in my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp">
  <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        local:MvxBind="Content CustomView">

    </LinearLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Any my ViewModel looks like this:

```
  public class CustomViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        public object CustomView { get; set; }
    }
```

The custom binding has also been registered in Setup.cs as follows:

```
  protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
        {           
            registry.RegisterPropertyInfoBindingFactory(
                typeof(MvxLinearLayoutContentTargetBinding),
                typeof(LinearLayout), "Content");

            base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
        }
```

Yet with all this in place, I do not see my view.

Answer (score 1):

MvvmCross already supports a primitive version of this. Although without DataTemplateSelector.

You can bind a collection of ViewModels to `MvxLinearLayout.ItemsSource`. You also need to remember to set a `ItemTemplateId`:

```
<MvxLinearLayout
    ...
    local:MvxItemTemplateId="@layout/layout_to_repeat"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ViewModelCollection"
    />
```

This is however super inefficient as it does not recycle views etc. So if you need a variant that supports DataTemplateSelector, then use `MvxRecyclerView` instead.